# Column data I am storing can have caret ^ in it. How to search for such column data considering that it is primary key as well

Tags: sybase

Example data

EEECC^QWERTYUIOP^1234

Column data I am storing, can have caret ^ in it. How to search for such column data considering that it is primary key as well.

I tried enclosing it bn in square brackets that to didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Should work with a regular expression

```
WHERE column_name REGEXP '[\^]'
```

if you only need to search for the existence of '^' in a column value

Comment: I want to search the key I have mentioned 'EEECC^QWERTYUIOP^1234'

Comment: @user3571396 You wrote that it was just example data, please clarify what you want to search for? Is it an exact match or substring or ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

select *  from tablename where column  like '%^%'

for Sybase ASE and would return any rows with one or more carat symbols stored in them.

If you want a specific row such as your key value then where column = 'EEECC^QWERTYUIOP^1234' would work fine too rather than brackets.